# How to work with raw date format in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Zapier to input timestamps of emails to Google Sheets. The format I'm seeing in Google Sheets is:

Wed, 28 Jun 2017 21:02:51 +0000 (UTC)

Is there a way to either change this (in Google Sheets) to 2017-06-28 21:02:51 or to help date-related functions to understand this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to extract date from string:

`=DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT("Wed, 28 Jun 2017 21:02:51 +0000 (UTC)","\d+ [A-Za-z]{3} \d{4}"))`

`REGEXEXTRACT` part extracts "28 Jun 2017". Then format the result as date.

**Edit:**

> Getting closer :) Error DATEVALUE parameter '28 Jun 2017' cannot be
>   parsed to date/time.

I think this is bacause of your regional settings.

1. Option: writing script, my solution wont work.
2. Option: Change File → Regional Settings to US.
3. Option: modify the formula so it replaces english names of monthes into their numbers. This would produce ugly big formula.

Comment: Thanks! However, this gives me "formula parse error".

Comment: please try semicolon `;` instead of coma `,`

Comment: Getting closer :)

Error
DATEVALUE parameter '28 Jun 2017' cannot be parsed to date/time.

Comment: Answered in Edit